# Ubuntu 18.04 No sound From Monitor Speaker (Connected Via VGA and Aux Cable)

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my PC. I want to play sound through Monitor Speaker. I connected monitor with CPU using Aux cable. Also selected "line-out" option in sounds option. Still monitor speaker is not working.

I tested sound by headphones and it's working fine. I am sure that My monitor speaker is ok and there is no hardware issue because it was working with Windows. I  searched for solutions and tried so many solutions but no one did the trick.

Solutions that i have already tried:

1. `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

   pavucontrol -> then selected "Analog Stereo Out"
2. Confirmed many times that no sound is mute in **alsamixer**
3. Selected "line-out - built in Audio" in sounds menu from setting
4. Confirmed that output sound is not muted.
5. Tried reloading alsamixer by `sudo alsa force-reload`
6. Tried by reinstalling alsamixer and pulseaudio

   `sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio sudo apt install`

   `alsa-base pulseaudio`

Trying to solve this issue from last 2 days but still didn't find any solution.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!